# Android crash on inflating view when on SDK 29 an using @color/material_dynamic_neutral colors

Tags: android, material-components-android

I am developing an app using Android Studio and Google Material Components 2.

The test version of my app always worked up until the point where I tried to install it on a different device using the "Run 'app'". It threw up this beautiful orchestra immediately after starting the app:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sk.fisplus.fiscell, PID: 18256
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sk.fisplus.fiscell/sk.fisplus.fiscell.activities.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at sk.fisplus.fiscell.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(ActivityHomeBinding.java:50)
    at sk.fisplus.fiscell.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(ActivityHomeBinding.java:44)
    at sk.fisplus.fiscell.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:37)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7148)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7139)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1293)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to ComplexColor: type=0x1
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1088)
```

The errors seem to be caused by me using "@color/material_dynamic_neutralXX" colors. It works fine on my Android  13 (SDK 33) device, but the app crashes on startup on Android 10 (SDK 29).

I tried to replace all the color references with hex values. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with this problem on Android 11 as well. Yes, changing colors on the applcation colors solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a frustrating crash on inflating a view while working with  Material Components 2. The culprit turned out to be exactly the use of @color/material_dynamic_neutralXX colors.

After taking your advice and replacing these color references with hex values, the problem was resolved!